# ESLint suggests to wrap for.. in and use Object.{keys,values,entries}

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have this function:

```
getLabels(state) {
  const labels = [];
  if (state.report.data.report) {
    for (const key in state.report.data.report) {
      labels.push(key);
    }
  }
  return labels;
},
```

Can you please explain what exactly I should do with my function to avoid errors detected by ESLint? It suggests to wrap for.. in in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype and use Object.{keys,values,entries} for iteration.

Comment: What is `state.report.data.report`? If it is an object, you can simply use `Object.keys(...)`.

Comment: How about doing what ESLint ask ? I mean it's litteraly giving you the answere, what are your looking for ?

Comment: you can directly use Object.key(state.report.data.report). [Object.Keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> to wrap for.. in in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype

That means

```
for (const key in state.report.data.report) {
  if (state.report.data.report.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    labels.push(key);
  }
}
```

> and use Object.{keys,values,entries} for iteration

That means

```
for (const key in Object.keys(state.report.data.report)) {
  labels.push(key);
}
```

but your code is pushing `key` instead of the value of the property, so could be replaced with

```
getLabels(state) {
  return Object.keys(state.report.data.report || {});
},
```

Comment: why @Tushar? it's passing `state.report.data.report` or `{}` to object.keys

Comment: but pls read again, @Tushar. `Object.keys(state.report.data.report || {});` returns `[]` if `state.report.data.report` is blank b/c `Object.keys({})` is `[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will need to use this pattern again but instead I will push `value`. Does it mean that I can use your first solution to solve the error `Object.{keys,values,entries} for iteration`?

Comment: yes @OlgaB. you can use either of the first two solutions. The first with hasOwnProperty or the second using Object.keys b/c Object.keys only includes the own keys of the obj.